# I am trying to reverse an int using java, for some reason when given 0001234 my program somehow reads this as 668 and returns 886

Tags: java, reverse

```
public static int reverseInt(int x) {
        String t = Integer.toString(x);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(t);       
        sb = sb.reverse();       
        String b = sb.toString();        
        x = Integer.valueOf(b);
        return x;
    }
```

is my code and

```
        int x = 1234000;
        int b = 24230100;
        int g = 001234;
        int s = reverseInt(x);
        int q = reverseInt(b);
        int y = reverseInt(g);
        System.out.println("this is y:" + y);
```

is my tester. g is my int value that needs to be reversed but it is being read as 668. any idea why?
when adding print statement for testing:

```
        String t = Integer.toString(x);
        System.out.println(x);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(t);       
        sb = sb.reverse();       
        String b = sb.toString();   
        System.out.println(b);     
        x = Integer.valueOf(b);
        return x;
    }
```

my inital print for g is 668 and the print on line 7 returns 866

Comment: `int g = 001234;` that's not the number you think it is. That's an octal number. If leading 0s are significant, you need a string, not a number.

Comment: Yeah, strings are also more suited to invert them in general.